# Run .jar applications per double-click with OpenJDK doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I wrote a java app called "MyApplication" in IntelliJ with OpenJDK. It displays a JFrame on the desktop until the user closes it. I've exported it as a .jar file with default artifact options. But if I try to start it with a double-click unfortunately nothing happend.

I tried to change the application to start with to java.exe and javaw.exe from the OpenJDK installation folder but that doesn't help. I also checked my environement variables from my windows system. I set them all like every webside from google says, they have to be correct. If I run `javaw MyApplication.jar` from command prompt nothing happens too. But if I run `java MyApplication.jar` from command prompt following error message occurs:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyApplication.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyApplication.jar
```

After a research I found out that a classpath could be missing. But I do not use any external libraries or other stuff. Just the OpenJDK and a JFrame object from the java.swing library. A second reason could be that there is a mistake in the 'Manifest.mf' file but that was created by IntelliJ and I checked it. This file should be ok. Here is a preview:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: de.java.configuration.Main
```

`de`is the first package in `src` folder. `java` the second and so on. `Main` is the java class where the main method is included. If I set a `-jar` between `java` / `javaw` and `MyApplication.jar` in command prompt it runs perfect.

At this moment I want to ask an other question. What exactly `-jar` means as java parameter in command prompt?

I can't open other .jars too. The same behaviors occurs.

So my target is that I can double-click the .jar on my desktop for example and the app opens. Like `javaw -jar MyApplication.jar`but with a double-click on the software icon. How is it possible?

Comment: "What exactly -jar means as java parameter in command prompt?" it means "what follows is a jar, not a class name"

Comment: Anyway, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE) explains it rather clearly